# nodejs, mysql, sequelize... %like% is not working for utf8mb4 collation column

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have `Session` table having `SessionDescription` "I like"... when I search with "I like" it works fine but when I search "i like" it shows nothing.The column `SessionDescription` is having `utf8mb4` collation.

```
Session.findAndCountAll({
        distinct: true,
        attributes: colsSession,
        where:{
          IsApproved: false,
          Id:{
            $notIn: ReportedSessionId
          },
          SessionDescription: {
            $like: '%' + req.query.search + '%'
          }
        }
})
```